# After insert trigger in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

I want to update the value of account table whenever a new transaction occur in transaction table.

My schema is--

**ACCOUNT TABLE**

```
create table accounts(acc_id number(10)primary key,
                      acc_type_id number(2)not null,
                      acc_balance number(20,4),
                      acc_interest_rate int,
                      acc_last_access_time_stamp timestamp(0));
```

**TRANSACTION TABLE**

```
  create table transactions (transaction_id int,
                             transaction_time_stamp timestamp(0),
                             transaction_amount number(20,4),
                             acc_id int,
                             constraint  fk_transaction
                                 foreign key(acc_id)
                                 references accounts(acc_id));
```

And my trigger is :--

```
create or replace trigger transaction_trigger 
 after insert on transactions 
for each row 
declare 
pragma autonomous_transaction; 
v_acc_id number(10); 
v_transaction number(20,4); 
begin 
select  (:new.acc_id) into v_acc_id from transactions; 
select (:new.transaction_amount) into v_transaction from transactions; 
update accounts
   set acc_balance=(acc_balance-v_transaction)
 where acc_id=v_acc_id; 
commit; 
end;
```

but it is not updating according to latest row. it works fine with 1 row but for another row it shows this:----

> ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows ORA-06512: at "SQL_YIUTMTWLCMDHJYTTHHOIHORPU.TRANSACTION_TRIGGER", line 6
>
> ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 1721

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select  (:new.acc_id) into v_acc_id from transactions; 
select (:new.transaction_amount) into v_transaction from transactions;
```

What? Forget the above. You are missing some basic concept if you write a trigger like this. Why would you want to select a value that you already have?

This does the job:

```
create or replace trigger transaction_trigger 
  after insert on transactions 
for each row 
declare 
  pragma autonomous_transaction; 
begin 
  update accounts 
  set acc_balance=acc_balance-:new.transaction_amount
  where acc_id=:new.acc_id; 
  commit; 
end; 
/
```

By the way, this is a really bad idea (autonomous transaction trigger). Check what happens if you do something like this:

```
insert into transactions values (3, systimestamp, 30, 2);
rollback;
```

The transaction amount is subtracted from the balance, even if the transaction is rolled back.

Comment: It's also a generally bad idea to try to maintain a 'balance' column.  It will invariably end up getting set to the wrong value somewhere.  Basic rule: never store that which can be computed.  Instead, set a 'closing balance' at the end of closing period, then calculate current balance from that when needed (closing balance - sum of debits since closing + sum of credits since closing.)